# Why do 9 divisions overflow but 8 do not?

Tags: numpy, overflow

Why am I getting overflow `RuntimeWarning`s for an array of 9 elements but not for an array of 8 (or 200, ...) elements?

```py
import numpy as np

# This works fine
np.zeros(1) / np.float64(1e-309)
np.zeros(4) / np.float64(1e-309)
np.zeros(7) / np.float64(1e-309)
np.zeros(8) / np.float64(1e-309)
np.zeros(12) / np.float64(1e-309)
np.zeros(16) / np.float64(1e-309)
np.zeros(100) / np.float64(1e-309)
np.zeros(200) / np.float64(1e-309)

# This gives "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide"
np.zeros(9) / np.float64(1e-309)
```

It seems I get warnings iff I have more than 8 zeros and their number is not divisible by 4.

Comment: That looks like a SIMD issue.  1e-309 is subnormal.  You'll get that warning if you divide an array of nonzero values by 1e-309, e.g. `np.ones(1) / np.float64(1e-309)`.  Perhaps an unused lane in the SIMD operation is being filled with a nonzero value.  This might be worth reporting to numpy in a new issue at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues. If you do, be sure to include which version of numpy you are using and the platform you are using.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I filed https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/25097